# .map is not a function error on nextjs with firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using nextjs and firebase for a project and would like to retrieve data from firestore. Im having a hard time fixing the ".map is not a function" and nothing seems to work. How can I solve this?

I appreciate any help

```
const [farmacy, setFarmacy] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const db = Fire.firestore();
    const data = await db.collection("Farmacies").get();
    setFarmacy(data.map((doc) => doc.data()));
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a method called "map".  Maybe you wanted to do something with the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) array in the snapshot?

```
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Farmacies").get();
    const allData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
```